Phase-space evolution of conservative ODE
I have a system of nonlinear differential equations:
$$ \frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt} = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{y}) $$
where $ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $\mathbf{g}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose I know that the ODE preserves the L2-norm, i.e.,
$$ \frac{d\|\mathbf{y}\|_2}{dt}= 0. $$
For simplicity, assume $\|\mathbf{y}\|_2 = 1$ so the dynamics is constrained to the $n-1$-sphere.
I would like to define a probability distribution function $f:\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$. This distribution function would then somehow evolve according to the ODE. I would like to find the (partial) differential equation that governs the time evolution of $f$, but I'm unsure of how to go about this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Perhaps you can use this answer in conjuction with spherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
